# SQL query syntax for count/sum

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Suppose I had a table like follows:

```
ID   RANK     SALARY
---------------------
1    Manager  10
2    Temp     5
3    Manager  15
4    Manager  25
```

I want to find the count of all managers and sum of their salaries

```
SELECT COUNT(Rank), SUM(Salary)
  FROM Staff
 WHERE Rank = Manager
```

I wanted to know if my syntax was right.

Also for calculating max/min/avg salaries, would simply using the aggregate functions like min/max/avg work? (Having both min/max salaries in same table).  I.e.

```
SELECT MAX(Salary), 
       MIN(Salary)
  FROM Staff
```

I was just wondering since it seems too simple.

Comment: Why havent't you simlpy tried it yourself?

Comment: Did not have sql on my computer so I was downloading :) But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me.  Aggregate functions are very useful!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by the looks of your design, you might be missing quotes in your first query:

```
SELECT count(Rank), Sum (Salary)
FROM Staff
WHERE Rank = 'Manager'
```

Also, you might want to see all counts and sums for all Ranks (not only Managers), all at once. If so, you should try this:

```
SELECT Rank, count(Rank), Sum (Salary)
FROM Staff
GROUP BY Rank
```

Furthermore, you might want to use multiple aggregate functions in a Rank-by-Rank basis, which would look like this:

```
SELECT Rank, Max(Salary), min(Salary), AVG(Salary)
FROM Staff
GROUP BY Rank
```

And, yes, these are simple queries. In general cases SQL is simple, it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, it is simple for simple requirements like this. So yes!